# Properties of an Argon based gas giant

Tags: planets, atmosphere, gas-giants

I am writing a novel where a habitable moon orbits a purple gas giant. In looking here and elsewhere I'm finding it incredibly hard to get a sense of the elements-breakdown of elements that would be present in a purple gas giant. This planet does NOT have to be habitable/have breathable atmosphere.

It's my understanding that with electrical charge that Argon appears purple. So my thought is to have a planet with Argon as dominant element. Ideal conditions would include the capacity for electrical storms/lightning that would make the planet glow purple(s).

So questions attached to this are:
*Whether planet would likely have a solid core (if so what of)?
*What other elements might need to be present to charge the atmosphere?

Another approach might negate the need for the planet to be a "gas" giant. Recent research posits that purple single-celled organisms ma have once dominated Earth's surface.

"There are a few variations of the Purple Earth hypothesis among scientists.
DasSarma's research has focused on halophiles, microorganisms that still exist today in environments with a high concentration of salt, such as the Great Salt Lake and the Dead Sea. They use their strong purple retinal pigment -- the same visual pigment in the eyes of humans -- to absorb light and generate growth, and he says it's likely that they've been present on Earth for millions, if not billions, of years."

So - could this alternate planet be one with big salty ocean full of purple dominant organisms and/or purple bacteria?

Either way-what is a reasonable breakdown of elements (e.g. 74% Argon (or Neon)/18% Nitrogen/5% Oxygen/1.6% Carbon Dioxide/0.9% Water Vapor/ 0.5% Trace)

Cited article: https://www.cnn.com/2017/08/04/health/colorscope-purple/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I'd be skeptical with the way non-sci journals reports about sci subjects, do some fact-checking before.

Purple coloured organism are purple because they reflect the purple colour (replace purple with any colour and the statement remains true). With a purple life form, you'd like an energy source which radiates in the complement of purple. I don't know perhaps yellow/green? Like our Sun, maybe?

Case at point: [purple bacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_bacteria) use [Bacteriochlorophyll a and b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacteriochlorophyll). The absorption spectra for the two [show maximum absorption in IR, red and UV](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/neuroscience/bacteriochlorophyll) (plot posted inline below). Feeding them blue and purple would starve the bacteria of energy.

If you do want a purple light energy source, the best colour to choose for the organisms using that energy is in the red/orange/yellow (perhaps maybe green too) part of the spectrum.

[image: bacteriochlorophyll absorption spectra]

Comment: Mostly purple colored organisms are purple to our eyes because they reflect red and blue while absorbing green.